# How to search and select text in dropdown using selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, dropdown

I am new to Selenium and i am stuck in one implementation
My requirements are

1. Go to Settings page
2. Look for the dropdown
3. Fetch all values from dropdown
4. Look for a certain text in dropdown
5. If the text is not selected,Select the particular text in  dropdown

My code is as follows

```
void setru()
    {
        driver.switchTo().frame("contentFrame");
        Select rudropdown=new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("DefaultOrganisationDropDown")));
        List<WebElement> drop=rudropdown.getOptions();
        int e=drop.size();
        for(int i=0;i<e;i++)
        {
            String temp=drop.get(i).getText();
            String actual_RU="000139, NEXTRAN CORPORATION - JACKSONVILLE";
            boolean flag=false;
            if(temp.contains("000139"))
            {
                flag=true;
                rudropdown.selectByValue("actual_RU");

            }

        }
```

But this is giving me error message.
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Cannot locate option with value: actual_RU

Comment: You're passing it the literal string `"actual_RU"`. Are you sure you don't want to be passing it the value of the variable named `actual_RU`?

Comment: I have given the code.Its still not working.
I want to select value x if its not there.
driver.switchTo().frame("contentFrame");
   Select rudropdown=new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("DefaultOrganisationDropDown")));
   List<WebElement> drop=rudropdown.getOptions();
   int e=drop.size();
   for(int i=0;i<e;i++)
   {
    String Expected_RU=drop.get(i).getText();
    System.out.println(Expected_RU);
    String Actual_RU="999425, NEXTRAN CORPORATION - JACKSONVILLE";
    if(Expected_RU==Actual_RU)
    {
     rudropdown.selectByValue(Actual_RU);
     break;
    }
   }
  
  }

Comment: Don't compare strings with `==`. Use `Expected_RU.equals(Actual_RU)` instead. Also, by convention, non-final variable names start with lowercase letters and don't contain underscores.

Answer (score 0):

It may works if you replace the below line in your code

```
rudropdown.selectByValue("actual_RU");
```

with

```
rudropdown.selectByValue(temp);
```

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a typo mistake. Use below code

```
rudropdown.selectByValue(actual_RU);
```

Instead of

```
rudropdown.selectByValue("actual_RU");
```